# MAUI App: 'Name' Property Binding Logs ViewModel Error Despite Correct UI Display

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I am encountering a peculiar data binding behavior in a MAUI application developed using Visual Studio 2022 Community and .NET 7. In a ListView's item template in the DataListView, I am binding to a property `Name` of the Model. However, the error log indicates a missing `Name` property in the ViewModel, with the following error message:

```
'Name' property not found on 'AppNamespace.ViewModels.ViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
```

Despite this error, the UI continues to display the `Name` property from the Model correctly and operates as expected. The compilation succeeds, but when the `PropertyChanged` event is triggered during runtime, the aforementioned binding error occurs.

**Abstracted XAML Code (DataListView.xaml):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:AppNamespace.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:AppNamespace.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:ViewModel"
             x:Class="AppNamespace.Views.DataListView">

    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Spacing="12"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Button Text="Back" Clicked="OnBackButtonClicked" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      RowHeight="100" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Data">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    TextColor="Black" />
                            <!-- Other bindings... -->
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**Abstracted ViewModel Code (ViewModel.cs):**

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> _items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Abstracted Model Code (Data.cs):**

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

I have attempted two solutions to resolve this issue:

1. Adding a `Name` property to the ViewModel. This approach removes the error, but I consider it to be an undesirable workaround because it deviates from the intended architecture of the application.
2. Adjusting the `x:Type` and `BindingContext` in the XAML file. This only affected the designer's IntelliSense and did not resolve the error.

I was expecting that the data binding would reference the `Name` property from the Model without any issues, as the UI seems to display it correctly. However, the persistent error in the logs suggests that the binding mechanism is attempting to find the `Name` property in the ViewModel instead. Notably, this binding error occurs during runtime when the `PropertyChanged` event is triggered.

I am looking for advice on why this issue occurs and how to correctly resolve the binding error without resorting to unsuitable workarounds.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Try `x:DataType=“models:Data”`

Comment: Also assign the ViewModel as the `x:DataType` of your ContentView, check out my blog here to understand compiled bindings better https://medium.com/@freakyali/leveraging-the-power-of-compiled-bindings-in-net-maui-4b3db6b9f4cb

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your comment. I tried changing the x:DataType to "models:Data" as you suggested, but unfortunately, the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: is that the correct namespace for `Data`?  If your app is behaving correctly, you can ignore the error, but the root cause is a missing or incorrect `DataType`

Comment: @FreakyAli Thank you for your comment and for sharing your blog. I read through it to better understand compiled bindings. Following your advice, I set x:DataType="viewmodels:ViewModel", but unfortunately, it didn't resolve my issue. Additionally, using x:DataType="models:Data" leads to a build error with 'Binding: Property "Items" not found on "AppNamespace.Models.Data"'. I'm still looking for a solution, so any further assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @json Thanks for your advice. My code is abstracted and namespaces seem correct. IntelliSense shows no errors and the app functions well. However, as a data binding novice, I'm unsure about ignoring this error. Could this lead to any long-term issues?

Comment: Can you explain what the error you are facing now?

Comment: Your code seems fine and I cannot reproduce on my end. Could you please show us how you set the BindingContext for your ContentView and how you consume the ContentView in ContentPage? Or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: For more info, you may refer to [Compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0).